# Adding initial entries in openldap returns- ldap_add: No such object (32)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to add two entries in ldap just below one another. But it's not letting me add. Error-
        adding new entry "dc=R2D2"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
    additional info: Unable to add entry 'dc=R2D2' because its parent entry 'null' does not exist in the server.

This is a new openLDAP server running on a Feora29. I've tried many modifications to my ldif file but it's still not working.
The LDAP expected structure:
dc=R2D2 -> o=TD

I have added objectClass: country on line 4 because it said:
adding new entry "dc=R2D2"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: Unable to add entry 'dc=R2D2' because it violates the provided schema:  The entry does not have a structural object class.

This is the ldif i'm trying to add via ldapadd

```
dn: dc=R2D2
dc: R2D2
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: country 
objectClass: top
c=DE

dn: o=TD,dc=R2D2
o: TD
objectClass: organization
objectClass: top
```

Comment: Unanswerable without seeing the database definition; nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:java]; and off topic.

Comment: @user207421 FYI, I have added no database definition. Only what comes default with openldap

Comment: Is Stack Overflow limited to Java? No.
And of course this can be answered.

Comment: @MichaelStröder The OP used the Java tag. I removed it. This is not a *programming* question, and therefore off topic. It is deed unanswerable without the database definition.

Answer (score -1):

The LDAP result code *noSuchObject* (32) returned for a failed add operation means that the parent entry was not found.

If `dc=R2D2` is really the **full** DN of the entry to be added, then you have to define a database with this particular DN used as database suffix.

For static OpenLDAP config method this would look like:

```
[..]
database mdb

suffix dc=R2D2
[..]
```

See also: [OpenLDAP Software 2.4 Administrator's Guide](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/index.html)

Comment: If that is the full root DN it is already there by definition of the database, and cannot be added. You can only add subordinates of the root DN.

Comment: Nonsense! You declare a database in the OpenLDAP config and of course you have to add the root entry for this database.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is because your ldif has an unnecessary space character at line 4 (after "country" like "country ").

I have been able to successfully execute ldapadd command with the following ldif that has no unnecessary space character after "country":

```
dn: dc=R2D2
dc: R2D2
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: country
objectClass: top
c: DE

dn: o=TD,dc=R2D2
o: TD
objectClass: organization
objectClass: top
```